# Get user number using intent request not working?

Tags: android, gradle, android-intent, google-play-services, android-pendingintent

I am justing trying to get phone number using `GetPhoneNumberHintIntentRequest` to replace `HintRequest`.
So just trying to follow google developer doc https://developers.google.com/identity/phone-number-hint/android#kotlin_2. But after following doc I feel this doc is incomplete.

[image]

```
  val phoneNumberHintIntentResultLauncher: ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> =
    registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result ->
        try {
            val phoneNumber = Identity.getSignInClient(requireActivity()).getPhoneNumberFromIntent(result.data)
        } catch(e: Exception) {
        }
  }
```

So as per doc you need to pass intent to `phoneNumberHintIntentResultLauncher` but there is no method inside `GetPhoneNumberHintIntentRequest`.

[image]

Even if you see doc then you realise that you need to replace `signInClient` to `getSignInClient`.

If any one know about above issue then let me know or any doc where I can achieve my goal.

Comment: Me too facing the same issue when I tried to update the deprecated code of the phone selector API. It does seem like the doc is incomplete about the new API setup. Please do share the solution if you find it. Thank you!

Comment: Even I am facing the same issue. Please do share the solution. Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 2):

Have been facing this recently.

Please change the result launcher type as follows.

```
    val resultLauncher: ActivityResultLauncher<IntentSenderRequest> = registerForActivityResult(StartIntentSenderForResult()) { result ->
        try {
            val phoneNumber = Identity.getSignInClient(requireActivity()).getPhoneNumberFromIntent(result.data)
            // Do something with the number
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Phone Number Hint failed")
        }
```

And launch the intent as

```
    ...
    .addOnSuccessListener { request: PendingIntent ->
            try {
                resultLauncher.launch(IntentSenderRequest.Builder(request).build())
            } catch(e: Exception) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Launching the PendingIntent failed")
            }
        }
    ...
```

The document is indeed incomplete as it seems.

Comment: Using StartIntentSenderForResult works. Thanks.

Comment: I am always getting ->"Phone Number Hint failed"  it goes in  addOnFailureListener {
                (Log.e("TAG", "Phone Number Hint failed"))
            }. Tried on different android OS level's

Comment: it says 16: No phone number is found on this device. Even though the device has valid numbers available.

Comment: I have 2 numbers in my device, but showing only one phone number using SignInClient.getPhoneNumberHintIntent(). But by using hintRequest able to get both phone numbers

Comment: I can see different results for GetPhoneNumberHintIntentRequest and HintRequest intent

Answer (score 1):

// initialise above onCreate

```
private ActivityResultLauncher<IntentSenderRequest> someActivityResultLauncher;
```

// declare in onCreate

```
private void phoneSelection() {
        GetPhoneNumberHintIntentRequest request =  GetPhoneNumberHintIntentRequest.builder().build();
        Identity.getSignInClient(RegistrationActivity.this)
                .getPhoneNumberHintIntent(request)
                .addOnFailureListener(e -> {
                    Toast.makeText(activity, "Error : "+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }).addOnSuccessListener(pendingIntent -> {
                    IntentSenderRequest intentSenderRequest = new IntentSenderRequest.Builder(pendingIntent.getIntentSender()).build();
                    someActivityResultLauncher.launch(intentSenderRequest);
                });
    }
```

// declare in onCreate

```
private void resultLauncher() {
        someActivityResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.StartIntentSenderForResult(), result -> {
            try {
                String phoneNumber = Identity.getSignInClient(RegistrationActivity.this).getPhoneNumberFromIntent(result.getData());
                binding.editNumber.setText(phoneNumber.substring(3)); //get the selected phone
            } catch (ApiException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(activity, "Error : "+ e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
```